# Android TV: Using tab layout

Tags: android-tv

I would like to ask if using TabLayout for TV apps is a recommended way for navigation or not ? 
The reason why I am using tablayout is that in my app i receive channels from a server and the channels belong to different categories

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using TabLayout for TV is not an good idea. Even though It supports on Android TV the user experience look was not so good. It is out fit for bigger screens and not give the Cinematic experience.

For TV experience, Google has created a Leanback Support Library which contains APIs to support building user interfaces on TV devices. To Show different channels grouped up in to categories - you should use BrowserFragment. It is composed with RowFragment and HeaderFragment.

For More Details for TV Design Guide lines:

- [Google Design Guide Line for Android TV](https://www.google.com/design/spec-tv/tv-apps/browse-view.html#)
- [YouTube APP for Android TV Design Information](https://medium.com/building-for-android-tv/building-for-android-tv-episode-3-381e041dfec7#.cxpnhgwau)

Comment: Thanks for your answer . 
I have not used the leanback yet , but my app appearance is like this one 
https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t35.0-12/13524075_10209831395931270_1902639903_o.png?oh=025aae16d83d6682768ac392ee26bf3b&oe=5791F073

do you think i can have similar appraoch with leanback ? especially the idea of having a sample previewer before playing the video and showing it fullscreen ?

Comment: Yes you can use leanback - BrowserFragment to show list of channels with specific categories. Next for showing sample preview, use [Picture-in-picture(PIP)](https://developer.android.com/preview/features/picture-in-picture.html) which shows pinned preview window on the same screen while you focus or select any particular channel.

Answer (score 3):

**Update 2020** :

Now there's official support for TabLayout on Android TV with **LeanbackTabLayout** Code snippet and screenshots available here https://developer.android.com/training/tv/start/libraries#leanback-tabs-library

Answer (score 2):

Google has a sample of TabLayout now.

https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-tv-leanback/blob/master/checkpoint_2/src/main/java/com/android/example/leanback/SlidingTabLayout.java

Here is the partial screenshot of the sample.

[image]